# Incorrect results using WITH RECOMPILE option

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

If there are multiple connections concurrently executing a query with different parameters in a filter condition and the `WITH RECOMPILE` option is used, is there any chance that the query may produce incorrect results?

Comment: Unless there is a bug in the software yet to be fixed something like this one that is fixed if you have updated your installation. [FIX: A query that uses parameters and the RECOMPILE option returns incorrect results when you run the query in multiple connections concurrently in SQL Server 2008](http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/968693)

Comment: If you are on [SQL Server 2012 or 2014](http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/2965069) then make sure you apply this one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This ought not happen, but there have been several bugs that mean it might, depending on your version of SQL Server, and which patches you have applied.

The relevant Microsoft KB articles are listed below:

[FIX: Incorrect result when you execute a query that uses WITH RECOMPILE option in SQL Server 2012 or SQL Server 2014](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2965069)

[FIX: A query that uses parameters and the RECOMPILE option returns incorrect results when you run the query in multiple connections concurrently in SQL Server 2008](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/968693)

[FIX: Different results may be returned when you concurrently run the same query with the RECOMPILE option in SQL Server 2008](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976603)